# ANTLR: How do I produce a tree with more than 2 children?

Tags: antlr

Given the grammar,

```
parse   : expr EOF -> ^(ROOT expr);
expr    : atom ('|'^ atom)*;
atom    : LITERAL | ('('! expr ')'!);

LITERAL : 'a'..'z';
WS      : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n'){Skip();};
```

And input,

```
a|b|c
```

I get a tree that looks like,

http://graph.gafol.net/pic/dsqoQhzgs.png

Whereas I'd like a tree that looks like,

http://graph.gafol.net/pic/dsrGWVUfz.png

How would I express that in the grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky. You *could* do it by using a [syntactic predicate](https://wincent.com/wiki/ANTLR_predicates) `(LOOK-AHEAD-TOKENS-HERE)=>` before matching an "OR-chain":

```
expr
  :  (atom '|')=> atom ('|' atom)+ -> ^('|' atom+)
  |  atom
  ;
```

which properly handles `a|b|c`, `a|b` and `a`.

But you might want to explain what language you're actually trying to parse: there might be better (more elegant?) ways to express it.

Why wouldn't you want to have an AST as in your first diagram? Evaluating expressions is easy when the root (operand) has only two children, right?

Comment: Can't you do it without a look-ahead if you change the `*` to a `+`? I'm parsing regular expressions. I think it will be easier to have all the alternatives as siblings because I want to randomly pick one. If they're nested in a binary tree as in the first AST, `c` would have a 50% chance of being chosen, and the other 2 would have 25%, whereas I want it to be 33% each... unless the user uses brackets.

Comment: Sorry, the `*` had to be a `+` (edited my answer). But no, then there's still a non-LL(*) decision in that rule. Give it a try, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I have to agree 100% with Bart's last paragraph.  The first AST makes total sense and what you are wanting to do with it doesn't.  It also makes it more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
parse   : expr EOF -> ^(ROOT expr);
expr    : atom ('|'^ atom)* -> atom+;
atom    : LITERAL | ('('! expr ')'!);

LITERAL : 'a'..'z';
WS      : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n'){Skip();};
```

I think this will do it by adding a rewrite rule but I don't have antlrworks right now so I can't be sure.  But it's close so give it a shot and modify the rewrite syntax if necessary.

Comment: That will not work: you can't mix `^` and `->` together in a rule. And if you remove the `^` from `expr`, it fails to properly parse single `LITERAL`'s. Try it.

Comment: Bummer... I just came up with something similar, `atom ('|' atom)* -> ^('|' atom+);` works great when there is an `|` but otherwise it fails as Bart said.